# ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/... does not exist (after lvextend and aptitude upgrade)

Tags: 14.04, boot, lvm

After resizing the lvm of my machine and - some time later, updating kernel of my machine, the machine does not start. Error: ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/... does not exist

What can I do here? Just downloading live-cd at the moment - what do I have to do then?

Comment: A complete walk-through of recovering from that error is not well suited for a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1):

the solution was to run lvm tool to activate the inactive logical volume. After exiting initramfs system was able to boot again.

After logging in it was necessary to run grub-update.